# Solve trigonometric equation with sin function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How could I solve the following trigonometric equation?

$$\sin(\omega t)=- \frac 1 2$$

Take the inverse sine of both sides:

$$\omega t=\arcsin\left( -\frac 1 2 \right)$$

$$t=\frac 1 \omega \arcsin\left( -\frac 1 2 \right) =- \frac {6\pi}{\omega}$$
and then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

see my answer:

when $\sin\left(2k\pi- \frac{\pi}{6}\right)=-1/2$  then , $$\sin(\omega t)=-\frac 12=\sin\left(2k\pi- \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
$$\omega t=2k\pi- \frac{\pi}{6}$$
$$t=\frac{(12k-1)\pi}{6\omega}$$
when $\sin\left(2k\pi+ \frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=-1/2$  then , $$\sin(\omega t)=-\frac 12=\sin\left(2k\pi+ \frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$$
$$\omega t=2k\pi+ \frac{7\pi}{6}$$
$$t=\frac{(12k+7)\pi}{6\omega}$$
take, $k=0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \ldots$

Comment: Much better +1.

Comment: Hi @Bhaskara-III, why you wrote $\sin\left(2k\pi- \frac{\pi}{6}\right)=-1/2$ and $\sin\left(2k\pi+ \frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=-1/2$?

Comment: because general solution to the equation $\sin \theta=-\frac 12$ is $$\theta=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}\ \text{or}\ \theta=\ 2k\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6}$$

Comment: Thank you @Bhaskara-III :)

Answer (score 0):

First observe for what values does sine value equals  -0.5

Then for those values equate to, then you will get answer for Omega as well as time period.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Given: $$\sin(\omega t)=- \frac 1 2$$

First: Rewrite the right hand side as a sine:
$$\sin(\omega t)=sin\frac{-\pi}{6}$$

There are two branches that follow from this:
$\omega t=\frac{-\pi}{6}+2k\pi$ and $\omega t=\pi-\frac{-\pi}{6}=\frac{7\pi}{6}+2k\pi$.
This simplifies too $t=\frac{-\pi}{6\omega}+\frac{2k\pi}{\omega}$ or $t=\frac{7\pi}{6\omega}+\frac{2k\pi}{\omega}$ for all integer $k$'s